# How does Vector3.Angle compute the resulting angle?

Tags: unity

I don't understand the concept of [`Vector3.Angle`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html) in Unity.

Can someone please explain in detail how it computes the angle? From which two points is the angle measured? It would also be really awesome if you could provide some diagrams for me understand it more, visually.

Comment: taking 2 vectors? it's just `return acos(Vector.dot(vec1.normalised(), vec2.normalised()));`

Comment: The concept is to determine the angle between two directions.  Or more succinctly, it's the concept of an angle itself.  Can you elaborate about what you don't understand?  Otherwise answers will consist of people guessing about how to help you, which makes for a bad question.

Comment: I dont understand how it returns the angle value.
As in like. From which two points is the angle measured.
Is it possible to provide lines and the angle visually so i understand how it works ?

Comment: I think that the over simplification of the Unity documentation is the confusing part, because it is actually getting the angle from the point of origin as you pointed out. Sometimes we just like to know how the API is doing the math. As I learn more, hopefully things like this will become more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

There is some confusion as to what the parameters for `Vector3.Angle()` are. This function takes two `Vector3` values. The documentation list them as `Angle(Vector3 from, Vector3 to)`, which I think the confusion is coming from.  It can be read as (and it should be)  **from** here **to** there. If you are thinking of these parameters as points, this from here to there idea gives you a line. However, if you consider the parameters to be vectors, then what you are looking at is an angle.  This is illustrated by the purple arc.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The lines you're looking for are those you get if you connect the point `(0, 0, 0)` with each of the two vectors. So, assuming that you have a vector `from` with coordinates `(x1,y1,z1)` and a second vector `to` with coordinates `(x2,y2,z2)` then `Vector3.Angle(from, to)` returns the angle between the red and the blue line:

[image]